# .Net Portability Analyzer for Core Telling me I am missing Assemblies, but says its 100% Compatible

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, portability

My goal is to move my codebase to being .Net Core so I can run my solution on linux.

I ran the [portability analyzer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36600.checking-compatibility-with-net-portability-analyzer.aspx) and it says that my code is 100% ready for core, but that I'm missing assemblies that are not in .Net Core.

My understanding is that if I want to use .Net Core I cannot add additional assemblies outside of it.  Is this incorrect?  Or is the analyzer just bugging out and telling me it's compatible to .Net Core when it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Net Core is not supported with this analyzer.  Once we fixed everything to get it on .Net Proper we were able to run the tool and get good results.